# Get URL Query String Parameters when there are multiple parameters with the same name using Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I have a URL that is comprised of multiple filters that are named and have corresponding search criteria, I cannot change the way these urls are constructed.

I am aware of how to get query string parameters in a scenario where I am just trying to get the value of one parameter, however I can't seem to figure out how to associate them together appropriately. For example here is the url:

```
/AllItems.aspx?FilterName=FilterA&FilterMultiValue=*FilterASearchValue*&FilterName=FilterB&FilterMultiValue=*FilterBSearchValue*"
```

I would like to get the values from this url so that I can associate Filter A with the FilterA Search Value and Associate Filter B with the FilterB Search Value

Answer (score 4):

you can use reduce to do that:

```
var u='/AllItems.aspx?FilterName=FilterA&FilterMultiValue=*FilterASearchValue*&FilterName=FilterB&FilterMultiValue=*FilterBSearchValue*'

u.split(/[?&]/).reduce(function(a,b,c){
  var p=b.split("="), k=p[0], v=decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
  if(!p[1])return a;
  a[k]=a[k]||[];
  a[k].push(v);
 return a;
}, {})
```

which returns an array of params instead of a string, allowing same-name params to repeat:

```
{   
    "FilterName": [
        "FilterA",
        "FilterB"
    ],
    "FilterMultiValue": [
        "*FilterASearchValue*",
        "*FilterBSearchValue*"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which works in modern browsers:

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let values = params.getAll("param-name");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParamsFromUrl() {
  var query = location.search.substr(1);
  var params = query.split("&");
  var result = {};
  for(var i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    var item = params[i].split("=");
    result[item[0]] = item[1];
  }
  return result;
}
```

**OR, TO GET MULTIPLES VALUES:**

```
function getParamsFromUrl() {
  var query = location.search.substr(1);
  var params = query.split("&");
  var result = {};
  for(var i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    var item = params[i].split("=");

    const key = item[0].replace(/\[|\]/g, '')
    const value = item[1]

    if(!result[key]) result[key] = [value]
    else result[key].push(value)

  }
  return result;
}
```