# Get url parameter: JavaScript not working if used third bracket in the name attribute of input filed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have used the below JavaScript code to get the parameter from the URL and checked the input field. It is working fine if I don't use `name="community[]"` third bracket in my input field. If I used third bracket in JavaScript code then it is not working.

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="type" name="community[]" value="<?php echo $comvalue;?>">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf('?');
document.location.href.substr(i+1).replace(/community=/g,'').split('&');
$('input[name="community"]').prop('checked',function(){
     return $.inArray(this.value,types) !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you're missing the `[]` from the `name` attribute in your selector:

```js
var types = ['A', 'C'];

$('input[name="community[]"]').prop('checked', function() {
  return $.inArray(this.value, types) !== -1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="type" name="community[]" value="A">
<input type="checkbox" id="type" name="community[]" value="B">
<input type="checkbox" id="type" name="community[]" value="C">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already tried this code. Its not working.

Comment: In which case you need to check your console for errors elsewhere in your code. As you can see from the snippet I added to this answer, it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Yes your code is working. But I have a problem? How to get community parameters to array?
`http://test/apartments/?price-min=200&price-max=2356&bedroom=3&bathroom=2&ap_features%5B%5D=washer+%26+dryer+connections&ap_features%5B%5D=dishwasher&community%5B%5D=business_center&community%5B%5D=clubhouse&community%5B%5D=covered_parking&submit=SEARCH`

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942257/get-url-query-string-parameters-when-there-are-multiple-parameters-with-the-same